# Shimano GRX parts compatibility with XT or XTR FD on Salsa Fargo. (BSA73)

Tags: shimano, compatibility

I am building a bike on Salsa Fargo TI 2019 frameset (ordered). It has BSA73 bottom bracket.

My current plan for the 2x11 drivetrain looks like this:

```
Crankset: Race Face Turbine 26/36 (Boost)
Bottom bracket - Chris King ThreadFit 30 + Chris King Fit Kit #21 (Wide)

148 BOOST rear wheel (DT350)

ST-RX810-R - SHIMANO GRX Hydraulic Disc Brake DUAL CONTROL LEVER 11-speed

ST-RX810-L - SHIMANO GRX Hydraulic Disc Brake DUAL CONTROL LEVER 2x11-speed

RD-RX812 - SHIMANO GRX Rear Derailleur 11-speed (42T max low sprocket)

CS-M8000 - SHIMANO DEORE XT 11-Speed MTB Cassette Sprocket 11-42

Problem Solvers for the Boost crankset - Salsa FS1328 [thanks thl33ter]
```

Salsa has Fargo Tiagra frameset with the same size front chainrings that paired with Deore FD driven by Tiagra 4700 levers.

I'm not sure if I can mount Shimano XT or XTR Front derailleur here; and will it be compatible with GRX lever and rear derailleur? What possible model should I choose to mount it on the frame properly (is it DirectMount)? 
The brand does not matter, it can be SRAM or other compatible. But the part quality is quite important (something like XT and up for Shimano)

Added this a little blurry picture I found on mtbr. Hope this will help.
[image]

Comment: Shimano does not publish any info for compatibility between Road/Gravel and MTB groupsets, so I'd be very wary about an XT or XTR front derailleur with a GRX shifter.

Comment: I was going to say that Shimano 11 speed Road/Gravel and MTB cassettes are not interchangeable, but looks like the 812 derailleur specifically is meant for a 11-42 MTB cassettes

Comment: Sure, the cassette is also present in Shimano GRX page, so I don't worry much about that. The main thing is the levers and FD.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I thought you were incorrect, but I have one source that believes that Shimano 11s road levers don't play nice with MTB FDs. However, it also says that Shimano 10s road levers don't play nice with MTB FDs, and yet the Fargo Tiagra does mix Tiagra with a Deore FD. https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1334/bicycle-front-shifter-compatibility/ And this different page seems to contradict the same site's previous page: https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1297/bicycle-front-derailleur-compatibility/#6

Comment: The other issue is the chainline for the crankset, though. I believe the RaceFace crankset has a 52mm chainline. The GRX 2x chainline is just 46.9mm, so their FD is set for that chainline. This may be an argument for a MTB FD after all.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Note i said "Shimano does not *publish*". I've had various folks tell me that road and MTB stuff does work together but can only vaguely cite 'the forums'. I can't point to anything documented

Comment: Found this video showing how Shimano 4700 shifters is compatible with XT FD. But it's for 2x10sp. (French, subtitles auto-translate is available): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcWHQdzQ9CM

Comment: Sorry, it was 5700. And Shimano compatibility charts shows that both shifters (5700 and  GRX) is in the same compatibility group https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-455

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fargo Tiagra with the Tiagra STI / Deore FD spec does work, although the hack nature of it tends to show. The shop I work at sells it.

From the pictures on their site, it appears the Ti Fargo frame has no FD housing stops anywhere, meaning along with the FS1328 you need a direct mount 11s double FD that can do 36-26 and accomodates 142 type chainline, as my understanding is that the adapter pushes it out to Boost in this case, and it needs to take a housing coming in from above.

Of current parts, I think that means you're getting FD-7025-11-D. I think FD-M8025-D also works but is no longer made.

Comment: Thanks. I found some concern on this video that fronts should have the same pull ratio: 6:00 https://youtu.be/myXVbwITvNk?t=360

Answer (score 2):

The Salsa website states for the 148mm rear spacing you need one of these adapters to mount a direct mount front derailleur [Problem Solvers FS1328](https://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/product_details.php?id=82139)

Source: [Salsa Fargo 2019 Spec](https://salsacycles.com/bikes/fargo/2019_fargo_ti_frameset)

I don't think you'll have any problems with those shifters and front mech.

Answer (score 0):

well, finally I decided to move to the 1x11, as the FD had compatibility issues, and I used to use an inline adaptor slightly moving the FD frame back and forth.

Comment: It's always great to see an update to a story like this! Could you possibly rewrite it a bit to make it more of an answer to the original question rather then an update to a bike building project? I think that'd be really helpful for future readers in your position.

Comment: Sure, GRX600 shifter was not compatible fully with the FD XT MTB derailleur. The chain is rubbing FD frame when on the largest or smallest cog (it is related to the initial setup). A small inline cable adjuster might make the rubbing less, but will not remove it completely. I have removed the FD.

Comment: You should write this comment as and answer. Not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

GRX600 shifter was not compatible fully with the FD XT MTB derailleur. The chain is rubbing FD frame when on the largest or smallest cog (it is related to the initial setup). A small inline cable adjuster might make the rubbing less, but will not remove it completely. I have removed the FD.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  If you are the original poster of the question you should [merge your accounts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so it's clear this is a follow-up from the asker.